# Is it possible to try Microsoft Accessibility MSAA in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

We are in need to try out an issue that our application becomes slow when MSAA installed.
The host OS has'nt been specified.
When I try to install MSAA 2.0, it says that the version is not supported in my system.
Is it possible to try out the same in my local system which has Windows 10 pro?

Answer (score 0):

MSAA can run in Windows 10 but not the version you already tested (2.0). You need the version 3.0 that is the one available for Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8.8.1 and 10:

[image: MSAA Versions]

Comment: That is Microsoft Automation which comes pre-installed right?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/which-version-of-active-accessibility-is-currently-installed

Comment: Can you please send me a link to download the same?

Comment: As per the given link MSAA 3.0 is Microsoft Automation, which comes pre-installed.